# RegExp for floating number in JavaScript with optional (multiple) commas and decimal points

Tags: javascript, regex

I searched a lot but could not come up with a RegEx in JavaScript, that would allow following points for a floating Number:

- Positive Numbers
- Optional, Only One Decimal Point allowed with any number of precision
- Any number of commas (0 or more) can be present before decimal point but no commas should be allowed after decimal point

Matches:

- ,1
- .0
- 0
- 1,0,0,0,
- 1,,,,
- 0.
- 1,

Mismatch

- .
- ,
- .0,
- .,

Please help me get a regExp for the above requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this.

```
^(?=.*\d)(?!.*?\.[^.\n]*,)\d*(,\d*,?)*(\.\d*)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uX5dV3/2)

- `(?=.*\d)` Lookahead asserts that there must be a digit present.
- `(?!.*?\.[^.\n]*,)` Asserts that there wouldn't a comma exists after decimal point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! It worked well for most for all the test cases stated in my question. :-)  But I want the regex to match 1,,,, also. I mean any number of commas are allowed before decimal point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Avinash!! It worked well for all the test cases stated in my question. :-)  But I want the regex to match 1,,,, also. I mean any number of commas are allowed before decimal point. I dont require third Assertion you have listed. Please Help