# Regex is working in Chrome but fails in IE 9

Tags: regex, google-chrome, internet-explorer

The following Regex is working fine in Chrome but does not work in Internet Explorer.

```
^(?=.*\d)(?!.*?\.[^.\n]*,)\d*(,\d*,?)*(\.\d*)?$
```

The Regex is for floating Point numbers with multiple (optional) commas and single (optional) Decimal point. For futher clarity please refer [RegExp for floating number in JavaScript with optional (multiple) commas and decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957296/regexp-for-floating-number-in-javascript-with-optional-multiple-commas-and-dec).

I have referred this link http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug. 
But the solution is not working. 
Please help!

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that works, or do you just want to know why that one doesn't?  Because that's a terrible regex anyway.  Why would you want to match things like `,1` and `1,,,,`?  And I don't see any need to use lookaheads in any case; they're just making the job more difficult.

Comment: Yes I need a modified Regex that can work in IE also. I have this sort of validation in my project :-(

Comment: In that case, you're just looking at the wrong question; we can do [much better](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[regex]+[javascript]+validate+number).